# (solved) Routing to Openshift CRC application through nginx reverse proxy and haproxy - i am getting desperate :-)

Tags: nginx, openshift, reverse-proxy, crc

After searching the net and especially stack overflow I now decided to write my first post on this platform.

I am running OCP CRC on a project notebook under Linux Mint 20. I created a basic hello-like Python/Flask application, that runs very well. Locally from the notebook, it certainly is no problem to call this application by the URL of **hello.apps-crc.testing**.

To make this application available in my local network, I installed *haproxy* and *bind9* on the notebook. *bind9* has among others the **crc.testing** and the **apps-crc.testing** domains defined, which then point to a dummy network device which haproxy is bound to, forwarding all requests from the LAN to the local OCP CRC.

This local DNS is then referred to by my central local DNS, so both domains can be resolved everywhere in the local network.

I have to make it that complicated, as this project notebook is also supposed to work stand alone for demos. It then also offers a WiFi access point and a dhcpd to connect guest machines.

I use the dummy network devices to keep things a little bit tidy, as there are some other services running on the notebook in VMs as well - each service has its own dummy network interface, which then is bound to by haproxy...

So far so good - works great, all connections (80, 443, 6443) for both domains work throughout the entire LAN for accessing the cluster through the web console and the oc tool.

Now the application is supposed to be accessed from the internet. So I have a public domain - let's call it **mydomain.org** - where i defined a subdomain **ocp4apps.mydomain.org**, which points to a DSL router, which redirects all incoming traffic to an *nginx* instance acting as reverse proxy.

This works great for a number of applications running on different hosts in my LAN and being assigned to respective subdomains through said *nginx* reverse proxy.

Now then, I defined a site **ocp4apps.mydomain.org**, that is supposed to proxy an externeal call to **https://ocp4apps.mydomain.org/hello** to the internal host **hello.apps-crc.testing**.

What then happens is, that on the remote browser **https://ocp4apps.mydomain.org/hello** gets replaced by **https://hello.apps-crc.testing/hello** which of course doesn't make any sense at all.

I guess, my problem is not the CRC, but my nginx configuration. And unfortunately I am rather a developer and no network guru :-(

Here are the excerpts of the config files - as brief as possible:

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
    server_name ocp4apps.mydomain.org;

    listen 80;

    # redirect all incoming requests to https...
    return 301 https://ocp4apps.mydomain.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name ocp4apps.mydomain.org;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html;
    error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.html;

    location / {
        # doesnt matter in this scenario
    }

    location /hello {
        set $hello_host hello.apps-crc.testing;
        proxy_pass http://$hello_host;
    }
}
```

I use this pattern of redirecting everything to https on all my site definitions, and so far it works well. Also proxying from https to internal http is no problem with other sites. I put the backend host name in a variable to avoid issues when the backend is offline. Tghe certificates needed for https are defined globally for the entire reverse proxy and all its sites - works well.

**haproxy configuration**

```
frontend crc_apps
    bind 192.168.2.11:80
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend crc_apps

backend crc_apps
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server crcserver 192.168.130.11:80 check

frontend crc_apps_ssl
    bind 192.168.2.11:443
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend crc_apps_ssl

backend crc_apps_ssl
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server crcserver 192.168.130.11:443 check

frontend crc_api
    bind 192.168.2.11:6443
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend crc_api

backend crc_api
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server crcserver 192.168.130.11:6443 check
```

As mentioned before, this part works flawlessly... i could have put the ip address for the CRC in an environment variable, but as it never changes, this works as well.

I then tried to add this line to the location definition in the *nginx* configuration:

```
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

This then changed the behaviour so far, that I now obviously get a response from the CRC, that the requested application is not available, because the host doesn't exist:

[error message from CRC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY0yh.jpg)

So I tried to set up an ingress for the external domain:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: overall-project-ingress
  namespace: overall-project-name
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ocp4apps.mydomain.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /hello
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hello-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

which then leads to a new error message, that the requested URL couldn't be found on the server (because of no TLS definition maybe, whereas the external call is re-routed to https by *nginx*?)

I am lost and would really appreciate some helpfull hints on getting applications running in the crc accessible from the internet :-)

Best regards

Axel

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the problem - but honestly I don't quite understand why :-)

I replaced

```
server {
    server_name ocp4apps.mydomain.org;
    # ...
    location /hello {
        set $hello_host hello.apps-crc.testing;
        proxy_pass http://$hello_host;
    }
}
```

with

```
server {
    server_name ocp4apps.mydomain.org;
    # ...
    location /hello/ {
        set $hello_host hello.apps-crc.testing;
        proxy_pass http://$hello_host/;
    }
}
```

So, basically I just added these trailing slashes - that did the trick, but I would be delighted to understand, why. I have a glimpse, that that might be related to text substitution, but I don't get it... :-)

If anyone could point to a good manual on how all these configurations really work, I'd be very thankful...

Regards

Axel